# Database with german words with their articles

Tags: database, api, dictionary

I need a list of common german noun list with their article (like das Buch, der Mann, die Frau... etc.) for a project. I would prefer them to be in an online database that has some API and I can pull from there, but if I can just download a text document with the words than it's fine too. Also bonus if there is a list with not only common words but all (or most) of the german dictionary. I did some googling around but couldn't come across the thing I needed, mostly because I am not sure where to look for the things I need.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about whether the articles would be included here, but the Yandex API seems to have German in it.
https://tech.yandex.com/dictionary/

On second look, this might be a good resource to browse as well.
http://www.programmableweb.com/category/dictionary/api